# Projection onto hyperplane is a closed subvariety?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

This is a problem in algebraic geometry that I'm trying to figure out:

**Problem:** Let $X$ be a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $k$, with $1 \leq k \leq n-1$. Let $P$ be a point in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and let $H$ be a hyperplane of $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $P \notin H$. Consider the projection $\pi$ by $P$ to $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. So for each $P \neq Q \in \mathbb{P}^n$, the line $\overline{PQ}$ will cut $H$ at a point $\pi(Q)$.

(i) Show that if $P \notin X$, then $\pi(X)$ is a closed subvariety of $H$. Also prove that $\dim(X) = \dim(\pi(X))$.

(ii) If $P \in X$ and there exists a point $Q \in X$ such that the line $\overline{PQ}$ is not contained in $X$, prove that the claim in (i) is still true.

**Attempt:** (i) I need to show that $\pi(X) \subset H$ is a closed and irreducible subset. I don't really know where to start. I let $H = Z(f)$, where $f$ is a linear polynomial. Then $f(P) \neq 0$. By applying $I$ to $\pi(X) \subset H$, I have $(f) \subset I (\pi(X))$.

I don't know how to proceed. Can I assume that $X$ is generated by $(n-k)$ amount of homogenous polynomials, because it is of dimension $k$?

How can I translate this projection to the commutative algebra side?

Comment: I don't think it's true in general that any codimension $d$ subvariety in projective space can be cut out by $d$ equations. One thing you might try is changing coordinates. For example, you should be able to assume that $P=[0:0:\cdots:0:1]$ and $H$ is the hyperplane $x_n = 0$. In these coordinates, the projection takes on a nicer format, and you should probably be able to show that the image is closed. Irreducibility comes from continuity of $\pi$ w.r.t. the Zariski topology.

Comment: Can I then assume the projection takes the form $\pi_P: [X_0, \ldots, X_n] \mapsto [X_0, \ldots, X_{n-1}]$? But how to prove the dimensions are equal though?

Comment: yes. Try proving that the image is closed first. Then my suggestion for proving dimensions are equal is take a maximal chain of subvarieties inside your subvariety and show that they project to a chain of the same length.

Comment: Is the statement still true if $P \in X$ and there is a point $Q \in X$ such that the line $\overline{PQ}$ is not contained in $X$? Can I use similar reasoning?

Comment: similar reasoning should work. Once again, prove that the image is closed, now take a maximal chain of subvarieties starting at $Q$, and induct.